# What is the meaning of CPU and core in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I don't really understand this after reading through [the document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-cpu). Some use a term like "CPU", but some use "core".

I am running Kubernetes in my laptop for testing purpose. My laptop has one CPU (2.2 GHz) and four cores.

If I want to set the CPU request/limit for pod, should the maximum resource that I have be 1000m or 4000m?

What is the difference (CPU vs. core) here in a Kubernetes context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove any guesswork regarding your laptop or any other environment, execute:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

...and then this for a particular node:

```
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

Look for `cpu` under [Allocatable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable) (which may have the same value as under 'Capacity').

Take into consideration that

```
1 CPU = 1000 millicores/millicpu
```

when setting "fractional" `resources.requests.cpu` and `resources.limits.cpu` for containers.

Comment: is this 1 CPU Core logical or physical core?

Comment: The meaning of CPU is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units).

Answer (score 57):

To clarify what's described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/) in the Kubernetes context, 1 CPU is the same as a core (Also more information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units)).

```
1000m (milicores) = 1 core = 1 vCPU = 1 AWS vCPU = 1 GCP Core.
100m (milicores) = 0.1 core = 0.1 vCPU = 0.1 AWS vCPU = 0.1 GCP Core.
```

For example, an Intel Core i7-6700 has four cores, but it has Hyperthreading which doubles what the system sees in terms of cores. So in essence, it will show up in Kubernetes as:

```
8000m = 8 cores = 8 vCPUs
```

Some extra information: These resources are managed by the kube-scheduler using the [Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) (CFS), and there are no guarantees in terms of overruns within the same machine and your pod may be moved around.

If you'd like to have stronger guarantees, you might consider the `--cpu-manager-policy=static` (CPU Manager) option in the kubelet. More information is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#cpu-management-policies) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/24/feature-highlight-cpu-manager/).

For more details on what your system sees as a CPU (and number of CPUs) on a Linux system you can see how many vCPUs you have by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how it can be `1 core = 1 cpu`? For my laptop environment, what is the maximum resource I can allocate?

Comment: whats the processor in your laptop?

Comment: it is normal intel cpu i7-6700, 4 cores.

Comment: so it's an i7 that means it has hyperthreading, which makes it look like that it has 8 cores. So there will be 8 cores/CPUs available to Kubernetes. Added more details to the answer

Comment: ` 8 cores = 8 CPUs` this seems to be wrong. I have a configuration with 2 CPUs 2 cores each, 4 cores in total, and kubernetes only allows to allocate up to 2 CPUs on the node.despite having 4 cores there.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh how are the exposed on your Linux system? (f you are using Linux) What do you see when you do `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: @Rico sorry it have been over a year, it's hard to tell now which machine I was looking at, I also changed jobs, so likely it was at the previous employment. Also people are not required to explain their downvotes. They might do it if they feel charitable, but is normal to downvote and move on. You do not owe anyone an explanation. I did not downvote you.

Comment: `1000m (milicores) = 1 AWS vCPU` This is not true. `1024m = 1 AWS vCPU`: [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_definition_parameters.html)

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that the [apisim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255956/kubernetes-meaning-of-cpu-and-core/53272444#53272444) solution is more suitable for my problem.

I run the commands and find out I only have two allocatable cores:

[image]

I couldn't understand why until I found this:

[image]

[Rico is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255956/kubernetes-meaning-of-cpu-and-core/53256326#53256326) about my laptop should have eight cores due to hyper-threading. But the Docker default settings throttle it to two.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in *[Assign CPU Resources to Containers and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/)*, it clearly says that:

> The CPU resource is measured in CPU units. One CPU, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to:
>
> - 1 AWS vCPU
> - 1 GCP Core
> - 1 Azure vCore
> - 1 Hyperthread on a bare-metal Intel processor with Hyperthreading

So, setting argument `-cpus "2"` tells the container to attempt to use two CPUs.

Also, CPU is always requested as an absolute quantity, never as a relative quantity; 0.1 is the same amount of CPU on a single-core, dual-core, or 48-core machine.

Comment: This last sentence from this answer, that comes straight from the documentation in my mind ambiguous. When I first read that I thought that by specifying 1 CPU you will always get the same amount of CPU resources on a single-core, dual-core, or 48-core machine. But experimentation shows that on a single core, you will get 1 core, and on dual core you will get two cores. This is quite the opposite meaning of this sentence from what I got from the first reading.